# Repair, renovation, overhaul

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Which expression or word should I use to describe "light" surfaces repair in room or house such as walls painting, plastering etc. As I understand `overhaul` means complex repair of house, but I need a word for less complex repair.

Comment: Are you repainting the whole room?  Are you replastering the whole room/ceiling?  Or just a few spots “that needed it?”

Comment: Are there a few synonyms that you have discounted? A reference (eg Thesaurus.com) you've looked in but found unhelpful?

Comment: cosmetic repairs.

Comment: I guess, cosmetic repairs is what I need. Looking for synonyms.

Comment: You could use [titivation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/titivate). It means tidying something up, making small repairs to it, decorating it superficially or a combination of any of these things. The point is that 'titivation' never addresses any underlying problems which may exist. Filling and decorating over cracks to sell a house would conceal the effects of but not address the subsidence which was causing the cracks to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following words to talk about your house:

1. **Refurbishment**. The refurbishment of something is the act or process of cleaning it, decorating it, and providing it with new equipment or facilities. For example, *refurbishment to marble cladding on external walls of Secretariat Building*.
2. **Minor (cosmetic) repairs**. For example, *Provision is made for maintenance supplies for minor repairs to office and accommodation premises.*